# Using jQuery/Ajax to switch images on click + PHP to call the images

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress-theming

I’m working on a WordPress site which shows a list of books — and each book has 2 covers (a book cover for the US, and a different book cover for the UK/world).

I have a DIV with 2 links (US Version and UK Version) — and **I’m trying to use jQuery and/or Ajax to switch the book cover when you click on each link.**

**I’m getting stuck because I need to call the image using a PHP function**, let’s call it “get_image”

Here’s my (broken) code.

HTML:

```
<a id="us-cover" href="#">US Version</a> | <a id="uk-cover"href="#">UK Version</a>`
```

JAVASCRIPT + PHP:

```
jQuery(function(){
     $("#us-cover").live('click', function() {
        <?php get_image('us'); ?>
    });
});
jQuery(function(){
     $("#uk-cover").live('click', function() {
        <?php get_image('uk'); ?>
    });
});
```

How should I proceed here?

Comment: So the actual container with the book cover is separate and under that container there are the two links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to make an example based on your higher goal. Of course it needs tweaking, but technically this is the most simplest example.

**Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/LUDwz/**

```
<style>
     #book_cover {display: none;}
</style>
<script>
    var us_cover = 'http://thebosh.com/archives/2010/11/25/Miley-Cyrus.jpg' ;
    var uk_cover = 'http://www.ashleefan.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/MileyCyrus.jpg';

    var book_cover = $('#book_cover');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // This sets the default on load
        book_cover.attr('src', us_cover);
        book_cover.fadeIn(300);
    });

    $('.triggers').click(function () {
        // Gets the triggers id which will be us or uk
        var this_trigger = $(this).attr('id');
        // Does the work
        if (this_trigger == 'us') {
            book_cover.attr('src', us_cover);
        } else if (this_trigger == 'uk') {
            book_cover.attr('src', uk_cover);
        }
        // Since the triggers are links, then lets return false, so the page woulnt redirect
        return false;
    });
</script>
<img id="book_cover" /><br />
<br />
<a href="#" class="triggers"  id="us">US cover</a> | <a href="#" class="triggers" id="uk">UK cover</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
     $("#us-cover").live('click', function() {
        $("#bookimgid").attr("src","<?php get_image('us'); ?>");
    });
});
jQuery(function(){
     $("#uk-cover").live('click', function() {
        $("#bookimgid").attr("src","<?php get_image('uk'); ?>");
    });
});
```